# How do i change function returns into an integer

Tags: python

Hi im kind of new to this just trying to make a quick damage calculator for a game using python 3.6 and i need to multiply 2 values that derive from user input

```
def armCalc(armV):
    '''Returns Armour Reduction Value'''
    return "%.2f" % ((armV / (armV+(50*70))) * 100)

def resCalc(phys, cold, fire, light, pois, arc):
    '''Returns AVG All Resist + Reduction'''
    allRes = (phys + cold + fire + light + pois + arc) / 6
    return "%.2f" % (allRes / (allRes + (5 * 70)))
```

Basically i need to multiply resCalc and armCalc but python says it cant because they're not integers and a search only leads me to input examples. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try calling `int(..)`?

Comment: Well, your code explicitly formats the result as a string, so I'm not sure why you're confused.

Comment: i tried putting the int() in various places but just returned different errors so im not sure if im using it right or even in the right place i have another operation function which will multiply those 2 values plus print a variety of other functions. and no incorrect return because im testing it i only put integers in i will eventually include except statements but im not there yet. also i have this in the main function

Comment: <code>print('Enter Resistance amounts: ')
    phys = int(input('Physical: '))
    cold = int(input('Cold: '))
    fire = int(input('Fire: '))
    light = int(input('Lightning: '))
    pois = int(input('Poison: '))
    arc = int(input('Arcane and Holy: '))</code>

Comment: @C.Blackett adding "int()" will convert something to an integer.  But that's not what you want (float()) and it won't help if you're still interpolating the results of such conversion into a string (see my answer, below).

Comment: You are outputting string and not float type. 

Anyhow, the expression (armV/(armV+(50*70))) is getting evaluated to 0.

You can 
just try `return (float(armV)/(armV+(50*70)))*100`

Answer (score 3):

In lines like:

```
#!python
...
    return "%.2f" % (allRes / (allRes + (5 * 70)))
```

... you're converting the results of your arithmetic expression: `(allRes / (allRes + (5 * 70)))` into a string using the % operator with a formatting string antecedent.

So just change that line (and others like it) to:

```
#!python
...
    return float(allRes) / (allRes + (5 * 70))
```

In this case I've also added a call to the *float()* constructor/conversion function to ensure that the entire expression will be evaluated using floating point (real) semantics rather than risk integer division if this code were executed by an other version of Python.

Comment: will that keep the decimal places to 2 and round up?

Comment: Then just call a `round()` method if you want to round up.

Comment: `return float(format((float(allRes)/(allRes + (5*70))),'.2f'))` will do

Comment: @Siladittya: that would be an inelegant way to perform the rounding.  Python already includes a function for rounding some number to some precision ... one which should be far more efficient than converting to string, then converting back to numeric.

Comment: @JimDennis yes you are right. That got out of my mind. Thanks .